# Unable to Show error message in cakephp 2.x validations

Tags: php, cakephp

I am developing the simple register form.And develope the model,controller,view classes.but i am unable to show the error messages in my application.

**User.php(Model class)**

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel
{
 var $name='User';
 public $validate= array(
                'username'=>array(
                        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                        'required'=>true,
                        'message'=>'Enter your name'
                ),
                'email' => array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'message' => 'Please enter your email'
                )
               );
}
?>
```

**UsersController.php**

```
<?php
    class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
     array('action' => 'edit')
    public function register() {

            if ($this->User->validates()) {
         $this->User->set($this->request->data);
                $name = $this->request->data['User']['username'];
                $email = $this->request->data['User']['email'];
            }
            else{
            $this->flash('register fail');
            }
}
}
?>
```

**register.ctp**

```
<?php  
    echo $this->Form->create('User',array('action'=>'register')); 
    echo $this->Form->input('username'); 
    echo $this->Form->input('email');    
    echo $this->Form->end('Register');  
 ?>
```

when i am click the register button above code is not showing the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer to my question. i.e

**User.php**

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel
{

 public $validate= array(
                'username'=>array(
                        'rule'=>'notEmpty',
                        'required'=>false,
                        'message'=>'Enter your name'
                ),
                'email' => array(
                        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                        'required'=>false,
                        'message' => 'Please enter your email'
                )
               );

}

?>
```

**UsersController.php**

```
<?php
    class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function register() {
         $this->User->create();
         if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {

          $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'welcome'));
         }
         else{
       echo"register fail";
         }
   }
   public function welcome(){

    $this->flash('register successfully','/users/register');
   }
}
?>
```

**register.ctp**

```
<?php  
    echo $this->Form->create('User'); 
    echo $this->Form->input('username',array('required'=>'false')); 
    echo $this->Form->input('email',array('required'=>'false'));    
    echo $this->Form->end('Register');  
 ?>
```

this is the correct answer for above asking question.The main mistake done in my above question was i am given **required'=>'true.'**,now given **required'=>'false.'** in register.ctp class.now problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you register action in user controller like this:

```
    public function register() {
         $this->User->create();
         if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) { //this way it automatically save or show error message if there is one
            $this->flash('register success');
         }
         else{
            $this->flash('register fail');
         }
   }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it shows the error message like  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

Comment: it will not shown the error messahes.it will work only required field\

Comment: my bad it was the semi colon, I edited the answer, please try it again

Comment: i tried and it works.but error messages are not shown when i am click a register button.only required attribute work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
add a helper

```
var $helpers = 'session';
```

then add the flash message as

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('error'));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is to show the validation errors, so instead of

```
$this->flash('register fail');
```

Do

```
$this->Session->setflash($this->User->validationErrors);
$this->redirect('/users/register');
```